# Can anyone recommend some good books or articles on working with time series?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, data-science-model, books

I've read a couple of guides such as [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/time-series-forecasting-codes-python/) link. I'm having real trouble getting to grips with how to use time series data effectively.

Anything to help with the intuition ideally with some case studies. I am currently reading Applied predictive modelling so anything with a similar pedagogy would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

One option is the book "Practical Time Series Analysis" by Aileen Nielsen.